# What game is this picture showing a character wearing a red bird costume from?

Tags: game-identification

[image: a character wearing red duck costume]

I found this game on a youtube video showcasing the evolution of pc gaming hardware but no information was provided.

The footage can be found in this YouTube video: [Evolution of PC Gaming Hardware](https://youtu.be/7Y4sv27J6co?t=16m25s)

Comment: At a glance I might possibly suggest GTA?

Comment: The other consideration is that since this is talking about PC gaming, it could also (and more than likely is) a modded version of the game (whichever one that might be).

Comment: However, the icon in the bottom left might be a good place to start.

Comment: I'm going to guess that that's not a duck costume, and that the mask is some form of plague mask or devil mask. As for the icons, the top left is something briefcase, and place item. Judging by the layout it's a game played with a controller, so probably console. Bottom right looks like a fabric swatch with a letter G, so I have no idea there.

Comment: Might be an Hitman game.
In this picture, the bottom left / upper right UI is similar.
http://telechargerjeuxtorrent.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Hitman-Blood-Money-XBOX-360.jpg

Comment: Also I;m curious about the game shown at 16:30 in the video .. It's one of the Mass Effect games, right ?

Comment: @Isak The one with green HUDs HP and AP? No, that's not Mass Effect, though I agree the buildings and weapon-on-the-back look similar. 16:33 *is* from Mass Effect, a close-up shot of [Joker](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Jeff_%22Joker%22_Moreau), probably near the start of ME2.

Comment: @Isak That's Fallout 3

Comment: @Fambida it is indeed a bird costume - this mission takes place at Mardi Gras. It is one of the weaker missions in the game, sadly.

Comment: Whoever edited out the title calling it a duck costume needs to rethink their editing habits.There's no reason to remove that.The OP specifically referred to it as a duck costume and they should be allowed to refer to it in that manner if they so choose.Changing a question because the answer reveals some statement was false is not at all good practice.If I say "a game where you place and remove cubes of mud", are you going to come in and edit it into"a game where you place and dig up blocks of dirt"?That's not the same I asked.Minecraft looked like mud to me.That's my opinion to have and write

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Listen, we know this affects you personally, but please relax; nobody wanted to by disrespectful to you, your family or other ducks. Nobody edited the "ducks" in, it was a mistake of the OP since the first version of the question (as you can easily see in the edit history of the question). Please accept my apologies in behalf of SE.com. Please don't sue. :-P

Comment: Nice mission, by the way. Besides wearing this duck costume, you can also kill a target by letting a piano fall from the sky!

Comment: @SJuan76 This has literally nothing to do with my username or me personally. I just don't like when people edit questions and change the meaning of a post because "it's not accurate". It is accurate as what the person *said* and what *they interpreted in writing their query*. Like I said, if someone described another game "inaccurately" are you going to edit those details out of their question because you they "didn't use the correct information". It's not fixing formatting or making their post easier to read and it changed their post to fit what *you* want to say rather than what they said.

Answer (score 55):

The game is called [Hitman Blood Money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitman:_Blood_Money) and the mission is called [The Murder of Crows](http://hitman.wikia.com/wiki/The_Murder_of_Crows/Walkthrough).

Comment: I would say this is a duplicate, but it gives a little bit more information.

Comment: +1 to you because your answer is more authoritative and gives no lee-way for doubting your knowledge.

Comment: @Auro an edit should have been suggested to the original answer IMO

Answer (score 44):

Judging from the UI of the Game this should be Hitman Blood Money, in one of the Missions this is a Costume you can get from a NPC.

Also, it's a Bird, not a Duck.

Comment: But... A duck is a type of bird. :(

Comment: @Fluttershy but a bird is not necessarily a duck.

Comment: looks like a red duck to me...

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Yes, but that's because you *are* a duck.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 lol nah. I'm just saying I can see where the OP got his inspiration from.